# Can GNU as process struct and function prototypes in assembly file(.s)?

Tags: gcc, assembly

As we know, assembly files(.S) would get preprocessing before assembling, but I found that after preprocessing there may be struct/function prototypes in the resulting assembly files, How would the gnu as deal with these prototypes? Just ignored it?

For example, the following command:

> gcc -E -o tmp.result arch/x86/boot/copy.S -Iinclude/ -Iarch/x86/include/

and the resulting assembly file (tmp.result) is:

```
# 1 "arch/x86/boot/copy.S"                                                                                                                                                                   
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "arch/x86/boot/copy.S"
# 11 "arch/x86/boot/copy.S"
# 1 "include/linux/linkage.h" 1
# 1 "include/linux/compiler.h" 1
# 5 "include/linux/linkage.h" 2
# 1 "include/linux/stringify.h" 1
# 6 "include/linux/linkage.h" 2
# 1 "include/linux/export.h" 1
# 26 "include/linux/export.h"
struct kernel_symbol
{
 unsigned long value;
 const char *name;
};
# 7 "include/linux/linkage.h" 2
# 1 "arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h" 1
# 8 "include/linux/linkage.h" 2
# 12 "arch/x86/boot/copy.S" 2
.code16
.text
GLOBAL(memcpy)
 pushw %si 
 pushw %di 
 movw %ax, %di 
 movw %dx, %si 
 pushw %cx 
 shrw $2, %cx 
 rep; movsl
 popw %cx 
 andw $3, %cx 
 rep; movsb
 popw %di 
 popw %si 
 retl
ENDPROC(memcpy)
```

but when trying to assemble this file:

> as -o tmp.o tmp.result

produce following error:

```
include/linux/export.h: Assembler messages:
include/linux/export.h:26: Error: no such instruction: `struct kernel_symbol'
include/linux/export.h:27: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `{'
include/linux/export.h:28: Error: no such instruction: `unsigned long value'
include/linux/export.h:29: Error: no such instruction: `const char *name'
include/linux/export.h:30: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `}'
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:20: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:34: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:36: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:49: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:51: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:58: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:60: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
arch/x86/boot/copy.S:67: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
```

It seems that the assembler can not deal with the struct in tmp.result. How can Linux source code(.S) get through the assembling?

Comment: What happens therafter with the `tmp.result` file? What's the next command working on `tmp.result`?

Comment: @Downvoter the next command working on tmp.result is: `as -o tmp.o tmp.result`, but it produced error, said it did not recognize the struct in tmp.result, so I wander how linux source code can get through assembling.

Comment: You could use `gcc  -save-temps` to save the actual pre-processed file it feeds to the assembler.  As Matteo's answer points out, it will be different from what you get with `gcc -E`.  You could also use `gcc -v` to see exactly how it invokes CPP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as` cannot process `struct` and function prototypes - they are just for the C compiler, and get "pulled in" in your preprocessing by mistake. In facts, if you look at the header that provides that `struct` definition, [you'll see](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/export.h#L25):

```
#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__
struct kernel_symbol
{
        unsigned long value;
        const char *name;
};
```

So, the header above *is* thought to be included both from assembly and from C, but you didn't define `__ASSEMBLY__` to tell it that you are including it into an assembly file.

Interestingly, gcc does have a builtin `__ASSEMBLER__` predefined macro to discriminate between an inclusion in an assembly file or a C file, but it seems that the kernel [does not use it for historical reasons](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/export.h#L25), relying instead on defining manually `__ASSEMBLY__` when preprocessing assembly files.

Long story short: to get the correct output from the preprocessor, you should be doing something like

```
gcc -E -D__ASSEMBLY__ -o tmp.result arch/x86/boot/copy.S -Iinclude/ -Iarch/x86/include/
```

(disclaimer: I'm not entirely familiar with the kernel build process, the line above may have other problems with include paths, or maybe the correct way would be to invoke `cpp` instead of `gcc` or whatever - I don't know)